# Grails actions getting called twice

Tags: grails, gsp, grails-2.2

The `getStarted` action redirects to `companyInfo` action which renders `companyInfo.gsp` and  immediately after the page rendering, `companyInfo` action getting called one more time. I don't understand what the problem is.

```
class MyController {
    @Secured('ROLE_USER')
    def getStarted(){
        def renderParams = [view: 'getStarted', model: [:]]
        if(request.method != 'POST') {
            render(view: 'getStarted')
        } else {
            def company = new Company()
            .......
            redirect(action: 'companyInfo', params: [id: company.id])
        }
    }

    @Secured('ROLE_USER')
    def companyInfo() {
        def renderParams = [view: 'companyInfo', model: [:]]
        if (request.method != 'POST') {
            renderParams.model.cmpId = params?.id
            render(renderParams)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the action? Which HTTP method? Use action name as `started` or something else other than `getStarted`. I would discourage using `get***` as action name.

Comment: I changed it, but doesn't help me.

Comment: `companyInfo` is called once when POST is called on the `started` action. I do not see it getting triggered twice. Tested in Dev Tool and Grails 2.2.4. How do you confirm that the action is triggered twice?

Comment: I'm using Grails 2.2.4 too, it's turns out during debug.

Answer (score 1):

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17281089/2711378). Grails trys to map `get*` to properties. And when the controller is called  grails tries to map `getStarted` to a property called `started`, calling the method. So, **Never Use `get****` as your action name**